# Deleting rows based on color and text in 2 different columns

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete a row if it HAS a red color in Column C AND if it DOESN'T have the words PO box in Column N. I have gotten it to where it deletes the rows that DO have po box in N but I can't seem to get it to go the other way and KEEP the rows with po box. Here is my code. The 13551615 is the red background color.

Also if there is a faster way to do this that would be great too. This takes about 13 seconds to run through my 3k rows. I only have like 20 rows with the color in them and I already sort those to the top. But I really just want this to work even if it takes a second.

```
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngRows As Long
'Find the last row in Column A
lngRows = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For lngRow = lngRows To 2 Step -1
    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngRow, "C").FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 13551615 Then
        If Not InStr(1, LCase(Range("N" & lngRow)), LCase("PO Box")) <> 0 Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(lngRow).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End If

Next
```

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to do this is to *not* use a loop at all. Instead, use `AutoFilter`:

```
  Dim lngRow As Long
  Dim lngRows As Long
  'Find the last row in Column A
  lngRows = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  With Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(1), Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(lngRows))
    .AutoFilter Field:=Columns("C").Column, Criteria1:=13551615, Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
    .AutoFilter Field:=Columns("N").Column, Criteria1:="<>*PO Box*", Operator:=xlAnd
    .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    .AutoFilter ' Turns off autofilter and shows all rows
  End With
```

Note that you don't need to sort the colored rows to the top.

Also note that this will work even if there are no matching rows.

**Caveat:**

Be aware that this will always delete the first row *after* the end of the data. (This *can* be fixed relatively easily if required.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for double loop. Set both conditionals in one statement like stated below. This should also be faster since it is doing only one loop.

```
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngRows As Long
'Find the last row in Column A
lngRows = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For lngRow = lngRows To 2 Step -1
    If Not InStr(1, LCase(Range("N" & lngRow)), LCase("PO Box")) <> 0 And Range("C" & lngRow).Interior.Color = 13551615 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(lngRow).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```